# PHP Notice: fwrite(): send failed with errno=32 Broken pipe

Tags: php

I was trying to execute the php script through shell given [Here](https://github.com/venomous0x/WhatsAPI/tree/master/tests) by :-

```
php whatsapp.php -s MobileNo Message
```

and  i got the following error :-

```
PHP Notice:  fwrite(): send of 111 bytes failed with errno=32 Broken pipe in     
whatsprot.class.php on line 1923
```

and line 1923 in whatsprot.class.php corresponds to :-

```
fwrite($this->socket, $data, strlen($data));
```

whatsprot.class.php is [Here](https://github.com/venomous0x/WhatsAPI/tree/master/src/php)

Is there any fix to this problem?

Comment: It seems like connection has been dropped by another side. Could you attach code before `fwrite`. How do you create the socket `$this->socked`, how establish connection, and how long time your script runs?

Comment: What does `$this->socket` refer to?  How is it opened, and what's the flow from being opened to the error you receive?

Comment: I don't see any error checking in your code. How do you know your password was accepted?

Answer (score 1):

It may be because your data contains 'utf-8' characters. I had the similar issue is caused by it.

> Exception: mysql_query(): send of 1462592 bytes failed with errno=32 Broken pipe

I used

```
mysql -u username -p database < dump_file # this is bad
```

to import the sql file contains lot of UTF8 characters (Thai language), but I didn't set default-character-set=utf8 for [mysql]. So the wrong coded data in the database caused that issue.